# Verb for gradual learning

Tags: verbs

While reading through an open source book I read the following sentence:

> This chapter covers basic Elm syntax that is important to **get familiar with**.

I may be nitpicking (no, *I am* nitpicking, without question), but it really bothered me. The verb is fine, but I felt it should read:

> This chapter covers basic Elm syntax that is important to **familiarize**.

My problem is, I'm not sure if it's correct. I failed at finding an example of the verb being used similarly. All examples I found were about familiarizing oneself *with* something, or someone else *on* something. English being a second language to me, I'd like confirmation either way, before I make an ass of myself.

Comment: ***To familiarize*** is used only transitively: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/familiarize - ...is important to familiarize (yourself) with.

Comment: An alternative form often heard is  *... important to **become** familiar with.*

Comment: I realise Josh61 has already given you the info you need; but anyway, another phrasing could be :
*This chapter covers basic Elm syntax **which is a prerequisite for later chapters**.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Collins Dictionary for English Learners defines [familiarize](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/familiarize) as:

> If you familiarize yourself with something, or if someone familiarizes you with it, you learn about it and start to understand it. ■ EG:  [V pron-refl + with]    ⇒ I was expected to familiarise myself with the keyboard. ■ EG:  [V n + with]    ⇒ The goal of the experiment was to familiarize the people with the new laws.

The notations "[V pron-refl + with]" and "[V n + with]" are meant to show that the word familiarize is always used reflexively, so your example would be incorrect:

> This chapter covers basic Elm syntax that is important to familiarize.

One possible way to use the word familiarize to express this would be:

> It is important to familiarize yourself with the basic Elm syntax that this chapter covers.